# Fallback for generated sourcecode with automake

Tags: autotools, automake

I am trying to use ragel to generate source-code and have an autoconf test to detect if ragel is present or not. I would like to keep the generated source in VCS so users won't need ragel to build it. But if present I would like it to be used.

Made a simple Makefile.am to demonstrate what I tried:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = bar.c

if HAVE_RAGEL
foo_SOURCES += foo.rl
else
foo_SOURCES += foo.c
endif

if HAVE_RAGEL
.rl.c:
        $(AM_V_GEN)$(RAGEL) $(RAGELFLAGS) -C $< -o $@
endif
```

however it fails with:

```
Makefile.am: object `foo.$(OBJEXT)' created by `foo.cpp' and `foo.rl'
```

Is this possible to do or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `foo_SOURCES = bar.c foo.c` unconditionally. If `HAVE_RAGEL` is true and `foo.rl` is newer than `foo.c`, then `foo.c` will be remade. If `HAVE_RAGEL` is false, then the original `foo.c` will always be used.

You might also consider adding `foo.c` to `BUILT_SOURCES` and `MAINTAINERCLEANFILES`.